# Truncating java formatted dates in oracle with TRUNC and TO_DATE()

Tags: java, oracle, mybatis

I'm not a particularly great person when it comes to Oracle, as most of my experience with databases has come with SQL server.

I have a java date that I am trying to convert to just a simple date (not including the time or timezone) in oracle so I can use it with a custom mybatis SQL statement that will be simply searching for whether a date is the same day as one inputted on the user interface. My mock oracle query mirroring what is happening in MyBatis is written below as my failed WHERE clause.

My dates are fed into Oracle in the format 'Wed Jun 19 00:00:00 BST 2013' and there's not a lot of flexibility I have around that format unfortunately.

My failed WHERE clause is this:

```
where TRUNC(s.logged_date) =  to_date('Wed Jun 19 00:00:00 BST 2013', 'DD-MON-YYYY');
```

It fails with the error:
    ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected.

My dates in the table are stored in a DATE data format, and I'm looking to produce a WHERE clause such that

```
 WHERE TRUNC(s.logged_date) = some date in the year
```

returns rows.

With the WHERE clause, I am looking for date equivalence irrespective of time. 
The format of my values in s.logged_date are in DD-MON-YYYY in a DATE data type column.

I really hope that you are able to help me with this, as I've been using any book I've had to hand and also scoured the internet for quite some time to try and produce a correct working WHERE clause.

Thanks

Comment: "My dates in the table are stored in DD-MON-YYYY format" - are they really? If so, *why* are they stored like that? Why aren't you storing them in a DATE field which is just a date, without any inherent format? You need to differentiate between the real data and how it might happen to be formatted in SQL tools.

Comment: You don't need to `trunc` the `logged_date` value unless it has a time element anyway; you can check with `to_char(logged_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')`. Your `to_date` is clearly using a format mask that bears no resemblance to the string value, so not surprising that fails; it's trying to interpret 'We' as a day number, for a start, from `DD`. Do you have to deal with different timezones in the parameter value?

Comment: @JonSkeet My apologies on that section. What I meant to say in regards to it, is that it is stored as a DATE data type with the data showing up in oracle as the format DD-MON-YYYY (which could be the default).

I'll edit my post for this.

Comment: Right. So I would try to keep string formatting out of that completely as far as possible. Does mybatis *really* need to use `to_date` rather than passing a parameter as a date on the wire?

Comment: @AlexPoole We do not have to support different time zones. The reason it is formatted with BST in it, is because we use a ORM for our SQL management, and as part of the mapped table, it needs a java.util.Date object be passed for logged_date, and those Date objects have timezones inside them. I've tried formatting using SimpleDateFormat to a smaller format and then parsing that format to a Date and it will still provide a timezone as part of it.

Comment: @JonSkeet MyBatis does not. My problem is that using the pre-generated WHERE clause by MyBatis will do a straight "WHERE logged_date = #{loggedDate, jdbcType=TIMESTAMP}" 

Which would likely be equivalent to "WHERE logged_date = _some date_" Which would not return rows unless the time components of those dates also matches, or is my assumption of this incorrect in Oracle?

Comment: @DanielBond: Hmm... it sounds like you need to change the MyBatis notion of your field so that it knows it's a DATE rather than TIMESTAMP. Is that not feasible? (I've never used MyBatis I'm afraid, so I don't know what's possible.)

Comment: I can certainly try and mess around with that when I have the chance to do so, tomorrow. It seems that MyBatis states that the JDBC type is "TIMESTAMP" even when the field itself is a DATE type (or DATETIME in SQL server). I'll try and report back on whether that works, or any of the other solutions work. At this point, I can only try.

Answer (score 2):

You problem is here:

```
to_date('Wed Jun 19 00:00:00 BST 2013', 'DD-MON-YYYY')
```

The string 'Wed Jun 19 00:00:00 BST 2013' does *not* match the format mask 'DD-MON-YYYY'.
You need to have the string formatted as '19-JUN-2013' to match the format mask, or the format mask should be 'DAY MON DD HH24:MI:SS TZD YYYY'.  However, if you choose to change the format mask to match the date string, then you won't be able to use to_date(), cause to_date() doesn't support the timezone.  You'll need to_timestamp_tz() if you want to support the timezone in your date/time string.

More info than I could possibly include here, regarding date/time formats, can be found here:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34924

Hope that helps....

Comment: You need `to_timestamp_tz()`, not just `to_timestamp()`, to use `TZD`.

Comment: Thanks Alex.  Good catch.  I modified my answer accordingly.

Comment: Will to_timestamp_tz() work with DATE columns for equivalence? It seems like it would be a different data type, or I could be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I'm answering my own question because I've managed to solve it now. But not through the use of all of the different custom functions, but better use of MyBatis functions with dynamic SQL. Using a "between" function in MyBatis on my SQL between 00:00:00 and 23:59:59 on the day I'm trying to find all records of, works better and retrieves all of the records required, without any need for database specific functions.

Thanks all for your help and suggestions.